# add content to a created xml document

Tags: java, xml, jdom, jdom-2

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileWriter; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.jdom2.Attribute; 
import org.jdom2.Document; 
import org.jdom2.Element; 
import org.jdom2.output.Format; 
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

try {
    Element FICHADAS = new Element("FICHADAS");
    Document doc = new Document(FICHADAS);
    doc.setRootElement(FICHADAS);
    Element fichada = new Element("fichada");
    fichada.addContent(new Element("N_Terminal").setText("XX"));
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Tarjeta").setText("XX"));
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Fecha").setText("XX"));
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Hora").setText("XX"));
    fichada.addContent(new Element("Causa").setText("XX"));
    doc.getRootElement().addContent(fichada);
    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
    xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("c:\file.xml"));
} catch(IOException e) {

}
```

I need to add the content to an existing xml document, not to create the document every time that i opened the program

Comment: Is this your code to generate the XML? Or to add?

Comment: to generate and add content, but if i close the programa the next time it will create too and replace, and i want to add

Comment: Of course - you are creating a new instance every time you call it. What you need is an additional function that is adding content to a given object.

Comment: or can i check if the document exists, if exists add else create and add?